# Generate JSON using Dynamic Variable in Shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to generate JSON output from my shell script.
I need to get Ram slot details of a particular machine and generate JSON using those details.
To get Ram details I am using `system_profiler SPMemoryDataType`
It produces details as follows.

```
    BANK 0/DIMM0:

      Size: 2 GB
      Type: DDR3
      Speed: 1600 MHz
      Status: OK
      Manufacturer: 0x802C
      Part Number: 0x384A54463235363634485A2D3147364D3120
      Serial Number: 0xE98388E6

    BANK 1/DIMM0:

      Size: 2 GB
      Type: DDR3
      Speed: 1600 MHz
      Status: OK
      Manufacturer: 0x802C
      Part Number: 0x384A54463235363634485A2D3147364D3120
      Serial Number: 0xE98388E5
```

From that I should form JSON like this

```
[
{"Bank":"0/DIMM0","Serial Number":"0xE98388E6","Status":"OK"},
{"Bank":"1/DIMM0","Serial Number":"0xE98388E5","Status":"OK"}
]
```

To extract separate details like bank, Serial Number, Status we can use

```
system_profiler SPMemoryDataType | awk '/Bank/
system_profiler SPMemoryDataType | awk '/Serial/
system_profiler SPMemoryDataType | awk '/Status/
```

I am sure that there is a need of Dynamic variable  to do  form json from the results. But since I am new to shell script I am confused. Is there any way to generate JSON from the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

$1 == "BANK" {
    bank = $2
    sub(/:/, "", bank)
    while (getline > 0) {
        if ($1 == "Serial" && $2 == "Number:") {
            serial_number = $3
        } else if ($1 == "Status:") {
            status = $2
        }
        if (serial_number != "" && status != "") {
            entries[++e] = "{\"Bank\":\"" bank "\",\"Serial Number\":\"" serial_number "\",\"Status\":\"" status "\"}"
            break
        }
    }
    bank = serial_number = status = ""
}

END {
    print "["
    if (e > 0) {
        printf "%s", entries[1]
        for (i = 2; i <= e; ++i) {
            printf ",\n%s", entries[i]
        }
        print ""
    }
    print "]"
}
```

Usage:

```
awk -f script.awk file
system_profiler SPMemoryDataType | awk -f script.awk
```

Example output:

```
[
{"Bank":"0/DIMM0","Serial Number":"0xE98388E6","Status":"OK"},
{"Bank":"1/DIMM0","Serial Number":"0xE98388E5","Status":"OK"}
]
```

Using within a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

system_profiler SPMemoryDataType | awk '$1 == "BANK" {
    bank = $2
    sub(/:/, "", bank)
    while (getline > 0) {
        if ($1 == "Serial" && $2 == "Number:") {
            serial_number = $3
        } else if ($1 == "Status:") {
            status = $2
        }
        if (serial_number != "" && status != "") {
            entries[++e] = "{\"Bank\":\"" bank "\",\"Serial Number\":\"" serial_number "\",\"Status\":\"" status "\"}"
            break
        }
    }
    bank = serial_number = status = ""
}

END {
    print "["
    if (e > 0) {
        printf "%s", entries[1]
        for (i = 2; i <= e; ++i) {
            printf ",\n%s", entries[i]
        }
        print ""
    }
    print "]"
}'
```

A one-liner:

```
system_profiler SPMemoryDataType | awk '$1=="BANK"{bank=$2;sub(/:/,"",bank);while(getline>0){if($1=="Serial"&&$2=="Number:"){serial_number=$3}else if($1=="Status:"){status=$2};if(serial_number!=""&&status!=""){entries[++e]="{\"Bank\":\""bank"\",\"SerialNumber\":\""serial_number"\",\"Status\":\""status"\"}";break}};bank=serial_number=status=""}END{print "[";if(e>0){printf "%s",entries[1];for(i=2;i<=e;++i){printf ",\n%s",entries[i]};print""};print "]"}'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I am working on a Remote Mac Machine from a Windows system.I am using plink to execute shell script which is in a local machine, I mean Windows. So If I use the script  given by yours I need to copy the script.awk to the remote machine which might make the process slower. So is there any possibility to have this script with default single #! /bin/bash file?

Comment: @CMb Yes you can embed it on a shell script. Please see update.

Answer (score 0):

There are some few libraries to do so.. One such thing is https://github.com/jeganathgt/libjson-sh . It is standalone shell script library, provides easy handy API's to generate json output in console.

Ex :

```
json_init
json_add_string "serial"  "$<cmd>"
json_add_string "bankinfo"   "$<cmd>"
json_add_string "status" "$<cmd>"
json_dump
```